# Highcharts: Comparing 2 lines with different dates

Tags: date, highcharts

I'm comparing 2 users of twitter on who receives the most tweets on a particular day, and put this in a line graph of Highcharts, the following mysql code I have:

```
<?php 

require('mysql_connect.php');

$artist1 = $_POST['dj1'];
$artist2 = $_POST['dj2'];
$dates_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT(tweetDate) FROM tb_tweetDetails");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dates_result)) {
$dates[] = $row['tweetDate'];
}
$artist1_tweetsADay_result =    mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tweetDate,COUNT('tweetIds') AS 'amountTweets' FROM tb_tweetDetails WHERE tweetId IN 
                            (SELECT tweetId FROM tb_tweetLink LEFT JOIN tb_artists ON 
                            (tb_tweetLink.artistId = tb_artists.artistId) where artistName = '$artist1') GROUP BY tweetDate");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($artist1_tweetsADay_result)) {
$artist1_tweetsADay_date[] = "'" . $row['tweetDate'] . "'";
$artist1_tweetsADay_amount[] = $row['amountTweets'];
}
$artist1_tweetsADay_result =    mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tweetDate,COUNT('tweetIds') AS 'amountTweets' FROM tb_tweetDetails WHERE tweetId IN 
                            (SELECT tweetId FROM tb_tweetLink LEFT JOIN tb_artists ON 
                            (tb_tweetLink.artistId = tb_artists.artistId) where artistName = '$artist2') GROUP BY tweetDate");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($artist1_tweetsADay_result)) {
$artist2_tweetsADay_date[] = "'" . $row['tweetDate'] . "'";
$artist2_tweetsADay_amount[] = $row['amountTweets'];
}


?>
```

I use this to collect all the available dates I collected tweet data (so also from other then the selected 2 artists)

Then I get the amount of tweets the user received that day, together with the date.
This all works nicely, and the output is as I expected.

Now when I put it in the graph, I put the array of the dates, as the xAxis Categories.
And put the tweetAmount for both artists in the data inputs to create both lines.

The problem is:

Artist 1 has data on 06-04-2013,08-04-2013 & 10-04-2013
Artist 2 has data on 07-04-2013,08-04-2013, 09-04-2013 & 10-04-2013 (so everyday that actually is in my database)

Artist 2 would have his data of 07-04-2013 at 06-04-2013 (since that value comes first)
Artist 1 & 2 have 08-04-2013 under the categorie 07-04-2013 since that is the second available date.

etc. etc.

Is it possible I could use the dates array, to fix the arrays of the amount of tweets, so that every missing date would have 0 assigned to it so the line stays correct with the date.

Comment: In preprocessing (when you get data from database) you can compare your data and then push 0 / null values.

Answer (score 0):

The two things that I would do to accomplish this:

1) use a datetime x axis

2) while pulling the data from your table, create an array of every date returned in addition to the arrays you are already building.  loop through the array of dates, and for each date, check the individual arrays for a value.  if no value exists, create it.

You will then have two arrays with the same dates, and you can plot them on a datetime axis and not worry about category index matching.